# Google App Engine edge caching via cache-control?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, varnish, cache-control

Does App Engine cache responses server side for either dynamic or static requests if I set `Cache-Control` headers? Documentation doesn't seem to clarify this either way https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/how-requests-are-handled

I have an API that responds highly cachable responses, so it'd be nice to leverage any edge caching.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the cache in your app.yaml file for static files

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  expiration: 10m
```

You can set a a default cache in your app.yaml file

```
application: my-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
module: default
default_expiration: "1h"
instance_class: F2
```

For caching json/response data from request handlers you can use [Memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/memcache/examples)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I'd like to do is skip the server processing altogether by caching the output of the execution as a static resource, such as you'd see with something like Varnish. By caching in memcache only, I'd still need to process my script at every request.

Comment: Well with App Engine you are are not allowed to write to the files system to create a static file so I can't think of a way to do it via static files. So how much are you trying to store? Maybe localStorage could work.